# virus scanning with c# and symantec scan engine

Tags: c#, antivirus

We have a c dll that was written years ago to call symantec's virus scanner, carrier scan.  Well it doesn't run on windows 64 and I have to get a new version up and running.  I found some code here - http://vaibhavkulkarni.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/a-icap-client-code-in-c-to-virus-scan-a-file-using-symantec-scan-server but for some reason when I run it I get the exception "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine".  I've disabled my antivirus, windows defender and windows firewall.  I don't have anything else that I can think of to disable so I'm not sure what would be causing the problem.  I'm getting the error on the 2nd call to `soc.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd));` Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If server is Symantec Scan Engine then they have their own .net api. Don't use custom, try original, it works great.

Comment: I did try using their sdk but their code won't work.  I posted on their forums and so far have received no response.  - http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/need-help-scanning-file-through-c-and-scan-engine

Comment: @geoff swartz take Wireshark and sniff the data being send/received. if you bought scan engine (well, i think you did :) ) you can write to support, but try to be as informative as possible

Comment: I'll look up wireshark tomorrow.  We bought carrierscan about 9 years ago and have just kept it up to date through v5.1.  But it looks like the api is the same for 5.1 and 5.2.  I downloaded the trial of 5.2 just to test to see if there was a difference but it was the same error message.  Thanks.

Comment: I've installed wireshark, started capturing my interface and run the code.  But I have no idea what to look for in this list of code that wireshark makes available.  I have uninstalled my antivirus so I have none on my system and my windows firewall is turned off and disabled in services.  Yet it still says "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."  I am running the symantec example code when I get this error and I've configured the scan engine to use the NATIVE protocol.

Comment: Read how to use wireshark. Filter by. Port you are using. And try to. Analyze what youn see. Well if everything is bad try. To write to support